# mysqldump throws an "Access denied" error, but only when run via logrotate?

Tags: mysql, cron, logrotate

I have a CentOS 7.7 box.  It's running mariadb 15.1

I'm trying to setup a process that will dump databases to the filesystem daily.  The dumped data will be managed by logrotate, with logrotate dumping the data and rotating the files, keeping only the most recent versions.

I've done this on other systems without problems, but this server isn't cooperating.

The /etc/logrotate.d/mariadb file contains stanzas similar to the following (one for each database on the system):

```
/usr/local/backups/database-dumps/dbname-SQL-dump.sql.gz {
    daily
    rotate 8
    nocompress
    create 640 root adm
    postrotate
    mysqldump -u root dbname > /usr/local/backups/database-dumps/dbname-SQL-dump.sql --single-transaction
    gzip -9f /usr/local/backups/database-dumps/dbname-SQL-dump.sql
    endscript
}
```

I've created .my.cnf files (permissions set to 0600, owned by root) in /root and /etc.

If this runs via the normally scheduled logrotate, it invariably fails with:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)" when trying to connect
```

It works if I explicitly run that logrotate config file using a cron job for root using a crontab entry such as:

```
50 8 * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate -f /etc/logrotate.d/mariadb
```

What am I missing?  Why would the mysqldump work when run via root's crontab, but fail when run via the normally scheduled logrotate?

Answer (score 2):

OK...I figured it out.  It was SELinux permissions on the /root/.my.cnf file.  (I've found information out there saying that the /etc/.my.cnf file would also work, but apparently it's not being checked in this case.)

I will add that I was temporarily led down a false path when I realized that exactly the same error can be triggered if the $HOME environment variable is not set in your environment when you run the logrotate command.  So, if you're seeing this and it's not SELinux, check your $HOME variable and ensure that the corresponding directory is holding the .my.cnf file.

Comment: What SELinux file type do you set on your `.my.cnf` file?